# How do you say these different forms of 'in'?

Tags: preposition

Having trouble finding good clear examples of the different ways to say 'in/into' in German. How would I say the following in German?

1. I'm going to the bank. (I'm at home; I'm going to the bank and I will stand outside the bank when I get there.)
2. I'm going to the bank. (I'm at home; I'm going to the bank and I intend to enter the bank and stay a while.)
3. I'm walking to the garden (I'm at home walking to some public garden and I'll stand outside the garden when I arrive.)
4. I'm walking into the garden. (I'm standing outside the garden and I walk into it.)
5. I'm walking in the garden. (I'm already in the garden and I'm walking while in it.)

I'm trying to untangle the options in my head: in (acc.), in (dat.), and zu. But then also auf (acc.), auf (dat.), an (acc.), an (dat.).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a general rule for *Wechselpräposition* (prepositions that can followed by accusative or dative); use the dative for locations and accusatives for destinations. Only in your example 5 is there no destination; you're in a single location and the action stays in that location. So in that case I'd say *Ich laufe im Garten.*. (There are several of ways to say "walk" in German, and without more context it's hard to say which is most appropriate. I'm going to go with *laufen* since is pretty generic and *spazieren gehen*, which is what you'd normally do in a garden, has it's own grammatical quirks which I don't feel like going into.) Confusingly, *zu* is used for destinations instead of locations, but it's always followed by a dative. Also, some grammars talk about "movement" with *Wechselpräposition* and say that if there is movement then you use the accusative. This isn't true, the accusative is used when there is movement to a destination, but if the movement is within a location then you use the dative.

As a general rule, use *zu* when you're going "to" a destination, and *in* + accusative if you're going "into" a destination. There's also ''nach'', which is used when you're going "toward" a destination. These distinctions can be subtle, and I'm not going to claim there is never any overlap, but I'd say you'd use *zu* for examples 1 and 3, and *in* for examples 2 and 4. But with large destinations, the size of a city or larger, you almost always use ''nach'': *Ich fliege nach Wien.* There is an exception to this though in that if the place has an article in the name then you use *in*: *Ich fliege in die USA.*

You also asked about *an* and *auf*, and yeah, this is where things start to get confusing. In general you'd use *an* (with accusative) when you're attaching something so it won't fall down due to the force gravity. So hanging by hook, nailing in place, gluing, etc.: *Ich hänge das Bild an die Wand.* But this meaning can become rather figurative and hard to interpret. To me, a lot depends on how much attention you're paying to something. So if you're going to go up to the door and just stand there then you'd say *Ich gehe zur Tür.* But if you're going to the door to knock on it and wait expectantly for someone to answer, or if you're going to the door because someone else has knocked and intend on engaging with whoever it is, then you'd say *Ich gehe an die Tür.* The "type" of location also seems to come into play. For example with a beach you might say *Ich gehe an den Strand.* You might think of the beach as a border between land and sea, and you're attached to this border as long as you're there.

You'd use *auf* (with accusative) when you're placing something, possibly yourself, "onto" something. It will stay in place because of the force of gravity and not in spite of it. For example *Ich gehe auf ein Schiff.* But again, the meaning can be figurative and hard to interpret. In this case, large open areas seem to prefer *auf*, for example: *Die Kinder rannten auf die Straße.*

In any case, I'm not going to attempt to cover every preposition that has something to do with location; there are a lot of special cases and exceptions to deal with. I'm not a native speaker myself so I'm not going to guarantee that I haven't gotten all the details right so far either. The positive aspect of that is I know how difficult and confusing this kind of thing can be.

PS. I came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rSO790y9a0) which seems to cover your question pretty well, at least the more general aspects. It should fill in some additional cases that I haven't covered here.

Answer (score 1):

In German you distinguish between the questions "wo?" and "wohin?". Examples could be "Wo bist du?" and "Wohin gehst du?" The answers are either Dative or Accusative:

Dative:

- "Ich bin in dem Garten."
- "Ich bin im Garten"
- "Ich laufe im Garten spazieren."

Accusative:

- "Ich bin auf dem Weg in den Garten."
- "Ich gehe in den Garten"
- "Ich bringe eine Pflanze in den Garten."

Dative answers questions where you are currently and accusative answers questions where you are going to go currently.

Comment: I took the liberty to reformat your answer, as the enumerations, and the contrast between them, was somewhat hard to find out from the middle of a text block. Please revert if you strongly disagree with this change for some reason.